# callback in route component causes Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This code causes a re-render loop, but I don't know how exactly I can approach this. I know the `setStartDrawingAction` and the `setSaveAndResetAction` lines are the culprit. But how can I fix this?

```
<Switch location={location}>
    <Route
      exact
      path="/analyse/measures"
      component={() => {
        return (
          <MapMeasuresContainer
            startDrawing={(callback: any) => {
              setStartDrawingAction(callback);
            }}
            saveAndReset={(callback: any) => {
              setsaveAndResetAction(callback);
            }}
            selectPolygon={(polygon: any) => selectPolygon(polygon)}
          />
        );
      }}
      key="measures"
    />
</Switch>
```

Comment: use `render` instead of `component`

Comment: Hi this works, what is the reason behind it? If you make it an answer I'll approve it. Thanks!

Comment: I'll elaborate and post as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When returning a function instead of a mounted component you need to use `render` instead of `component`.

When you use `component` the router uses `React.createElement` to create a new React element from the given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the component prop, you would create a new component every render

[docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#component)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use render instead of component.

The problem is every time when you pass as function to component prop it remounts again, like Parsing the JSX does not call it. It just ends up creating the function expression. So basically it creates a new anonymous type each time, causing re-mounting of the dom.

If we want to pass prop to Component, we need to use the render method for preventing remounting.